# Python regex manipulation extract email id

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

First, I want to grab this kind of string from a text file

**{kevin.knerr, sam.mcgettrick, mike.grahs}@google.com.au**

And then **convert it to separate strings** such as

*kevin.knerr@google.com.au*

*sam.mcgettrick@google.com.au*

*mike.grahs@google.com.au*

For **example text file** can be as:

Some gibberish words

**{kevin.knerr, sam.mcgettrick, mike.grahs}@google.com.au**

Some Gibberish words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, better grab the part in `{}` and use some programming logic afterwards. You can grab the different parts with:

```
\{(?P<individual>[^{}]+)\}@(?P<domain>\S+)
# looks for {
# captures everything not } into the group individual
# looks for @ afterwards
# saves everything not a whitespace into the group domain
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0lI7/1).
In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
rx = r'\{(?P<individual>[^{}]+)\}@(?P<domain>\S+)'
string = 'gibberish {kevin.knerr, sam.mcgettrick, mike.grahs}@google.com.au gibberish'
for match in re.finditer(rx, string):
    print match.group('individual')
    print match.group('domain')
```

Answer (score 0):

*Python Code*

```
ip = "{kevin.knerr, sam.mcgettrick, mike.grahs}@google.com.au"  
arr = re.match(r"\{([^\}]+)\}(\@\S+$)", ip)

#Using split for solution

for x in arr.group(1).split(","):
    print (x.strip() + arr.group(2))

#Regex Based solution

arr1 = re.findall(r"([^, ]+)", arr.group(1))
for x in arr1:
    print (x + arr.group(2))
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/BwGnzp)**

Comment: No need to escape the { in the document class. The @sign neither.

Comment: @Jan I know but I am habituated of `escaping` those in general